# Using .htaccess to redirect URL

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help from a Star Trek fan :)

I need to have .htaccess rewrite all URLs that point to [http://trekcore.com/blog/{article](http://trekcore.com/blog/%7Barticle) url} (or https:// or with/without the www) to [https://blog.trekcore.com/{article](https://blog.trekcore.com/%7Barticle) url}

Would anyone be able to help? It seems simple, but I'm not a coder and all my attempts at modifying other codes I've found online have not worked. It may have something to do with blog.trekcore.com being on a different server than trekcore.com where the .htaccess file would be used.

For a specific example, if someone clicks an old link to the URL http://trekcore.com/blog/2013/09/blast-from-the-past-1999s-photon-torpedo-media-kit/ it should redirect to http://blog.trekcore.com/2013/09/blast-from-the-past-1999s-photon-torpedo-media-kit/

Many thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the current .htaccess is blank.